# GMP Library - File I/O

Tags: c++, g++, gmp

Okay. So I'm using GMP library to calculate big numbers. I've got code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <gmp.h>


using std::cout;
using std::endl;


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("data.txt", "wt");
    int number=atoi(argv[1]), i=1;
    mpz_t a; mpz_init(a);
    mpz_t b; mpz_init(b);
    mpz_set_ui(b, 1);
    cout<<a<<endl;
    for (; number>0; number--, i++)
    {
        cout<<i<<". "<<b<<endl;
        mpz_add(b,b,a);
        mpz_sub(a,b,a);
    }
    mpz_clear(a);
    mpz_clear(b);
    fclose(file);
}
```

And I wanted to print numbers (a,b) to a `.txt` file. How can I do it? Tried `fprintf()`, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: (why not use `gmpxx.h`?) Just like you are using `cout<<a`, you could have an `std::ofstream f` and do `f<<a`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`gmp_fprintf()`](https://gmplib.org/manual/Formatted-Output-Functions.html#Formatted-Output-Functions).

The format specifier will be `%Zd` for `mpz_t`, so the code will be like

```
gmp_fprintf(file, "%Zd\n%Zd\n", a, b);
```

Other format specifiers and samples are in [GNU MP 6.1.0: Formatted Output Strings](https://gmplib.org/manual/Formatted-Output-Strings.html#Formatted-Output-Strings)